# Unrecognized selector sent to instance with creating toolbarbutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I need create web browser without storyboard. I overwrite init method. It's looks like your controller class (the target of the button action) is being released before the button fires. The button is likely retained by its superview.

```
-(id) init {

    self = [[super init] autorelease];

    myWV = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [self loadPage];
    });

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 90 , self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:myWV action:nil];
    back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"<" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:myWV action:@selector(goBack)];
    refresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:myWV action:@selector(reload)];
    stop = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop target:myWV action:@selector(stopLoading)];
    forward = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@">" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:myWV action:@selector(goForward)];


    [items addObject:back];
    [items addObject:spacer];
    [items addObject:refresh];
    [items addObject:spacer];
    [items addObject:stop];
    [items addObject:spacer];
    [items addObject:forward];


    [toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];


    [items release];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];

    return self;

}
```

Error text:

```
2016-03-02 09:04:15.922 MerTask[12971:1157926] -[WebViewController addTopBarButton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d72734e50
2016-03-02 09:04:15.963 MerTask[12971:1157926] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WebViewController addTopBarButton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d72734e50'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3a5e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ee1edeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3ae48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2fb90a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2fb4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MerTask                             0x000000010e03c129 -[WebViewController viewDidLoad] + 73
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010f8e8f98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010f8e92e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   MerTask                             0x000000010e03b97a -[WebViewController init] + 138
    9   MerTask                             0x000000010e03c2eb -[MyTabBar init] + 139
    10  MerTask                             0x000000010e03b5e0 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 64
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010f7491f1 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010f74a397 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010f750cc6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010f74de7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112be3754 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112be3ac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2d1a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2c795c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2c6e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2c6828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010f74d7cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010f752610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    23  MerTask                             0x000000010e03b8d3 main + 99
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011199392d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Maybe somebody know what's happened?

Comment: you dont need to do  `[items release];` as it is handled by ARC nowadays

Comment: in my task i need developing without ARC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `[WebViewController addTopBarButton]:`--> on your `WebViewController` you have created the `addTopBarButton`, but you have not implemented the method. Do this.

```
-(void)addTopBarButton{

}
```

**or**

```
-(IBAction)addTopBarButton:(Id)Sender{

}
```

**Choice-2**

Right-click the `addTopBarButton` button in your Storyboard. Remove the action to `addTopBarButton:`.

Comment: @GlebBelyaev -- not like sometimes it happen always

Comment: @GlebBelyaev -- if my answer is useful give the tick mark for the answer, it is useful for future